# Open Source PDFViewer Javafx

Tags: pdf, javafx, pdf-viewer

I want a pdf file to be displayed into my javafx application . Till now I have tried many things without luck including pdf.js html pdf viewer but I am getting below exception :

```
 Caused by: netscape.javascript.JSException: SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u8216'
```

Do anyone know any easier way of doing this that should be free and open source. Thanks.

Comment: I have a paid version of Acrobat Reader. I use it to turn the `PDF` into `HTML`. I then just use `WebView` to display the `HTML`. You can use a free online `PDF`to `HTML` converter. [This](https://www.idrsolutions.com/online-pdf-to-html5-converter/) is a good one.

Comment: But I want it to be displayed into my offline application. PDF is generated offline by the application and should be displayed there

Comment: Once you have converted the `PDF` into `HTML` you just put the files in a folder.

Comment: The other thing you can do is use [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) to write your own converter. You could convert the `PDF` to images and use the images to view the `PDF`.

Comment: I will try that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created an app you can check out. [Here](https://github.com/sedj601/PDFToHTMLExampleApp). You could probably find a free application that converts `PDF` to `HTML`. This conversion was done using https://www.idrsolutions.com/online-pdf-to-html5-converter/. I personally use Acrobat Reader to convert my files and I am currently trying to implement all of the different functions I want my app to have.

```
import java.io.File;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class PDFToHTMLExampleApp extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        File file = new File("CookBook/index.html");

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.load(file.toURI().toString());

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(webView);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 1000);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

The reason I chose this site for conversion over others is that they already have a zoom function and a function to handle the pages. The downfall is that they have disabled the search function.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But my limitation is I cannot convert PDF to html manually.

Comment: Hi, you could always try JOD converter or qoppa to convert the pdf's to html. I can't use this solution because im scared the conversion from pdf to html wont be the same.

Comment: Hello @JpSilver. I think one of the best things to do now is to convert the PDF to images using [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/). Then use an `ImageView` to display the different pages.